# Output not getting redirected properly

Tags: python, bash, logging

I am running this command through on bash console through iTerm

```
{ cd /usr/local/path/to/code; echo "hi1"; sudo chmod 777 /tmp/dissolve.log; echo "hi2"; python someapp/runner.py dissolve; echo "hi3"; } > /tmp/dissolve.log &
```

on tailing the file i get :

```
tail: /tmp/dissolve.log: file truncated
hi1
hi2
```

I am not able to figure out why i am not getting output of file `python someapp/runner.py dissolve`, when i do <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, the expected output is appearing on `tail` log.

code snippet from `runner.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    program_name = sys.argv[1]
    if program_name == 'dissolve':
        obj = SomeClass()  # this is properly imported
        obj.some_function() # this has lot of `print` statements, which i intened to catch in '/tmp/dissolve.log'
```

Is the initial `print` inside `some_function()` passing the values some where other than the `/tmp/dissolve.log`?

Any suggestion why this could be happening?

Comment: Seems like a buffering issue.  Can you flush the buffer periodically inside `obj.some_function()` and see if that helps?  You can also prefix the python command with `stdbuf -oL` to force line buffering.  For more info, see [Buffering in standard streams](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a [buffering](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation) issue, as you are sending the output to a file.  You can force line buffering with `stdbuf`, like this:

```
{ cd /usr/local/path/to/code;
  echo "hi1";
  sudo chmod 777 /tmp/dissolve.log;
  echo "hi2";
  stdbuf -oL python someapp/runner.py dissolve;
  echo "hi3"; } > /tmp/dissolve.log &
```

Comment: `print` are still not getting in `tail`... :( looking up for how to flush the buffer periodically!

Comment: i added `sys.stdout.flush()` before the execution of function in python, not working!! :(

Comment: What if you ran the python script separately, without redirecting its output?

Comment: i added the `flush` as you suggested in my python script, wrote the output in a file directly from code, works now....!! :)